# How do I style blockquotes on tumblr theme?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I want my `blockquotes` aligned, not overlapping. The issue can be seen here: http://ymirsgirlfriend.tumblr.com/post/86505956778/caramelcheese-carry-on-my-wayward-butt

Example Image of requirement.

[image]

Here is my CSS:

```
blockquote {
    display: block;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:10px;
    border:1px solid #bbb4b4;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius:0px;
    color:#aaaaaa;
    background-color: #fafaf7;
    width:180px;
    margin-left:0px;
    cursor:url(http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/7673/cursorw.png);
}
```

Thank you to anyone who looks at the question!

Comment: @Paulie_D `{color:blockquote}` is a Tumblr custom variable: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#theme-options

Comment: Then I would suggest we need to see the actual output CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D Added it, just for you! :D

Comment: Oh...and what does aligned mean? Aligned how?

Comment: @Paulie_D I can only presume OP wants the start / ends to be the same, but I will leave that for OP to confirm.

Comment: ...also, the `center' element has been removed from HTML5 and should no longer be used.

Comment: Aligned on the right like this? http://i.imgur.com/0JPhMeG.png

Comment: Not actually sure that's possible with CSS...I'd have to think.

Comment: If the blockquotes are nested (which it looks like they are) padding:5px 5px 5px 5px; will keep indenting every blockquote

Comment: so I would get rid of the width and also try padding: 5px 0;

Comment: I posted the code for my screenshot. I'd suggest you also increase the [(font) size](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/211/is-there-an-optimal-font-size) and [contrast](http://contrastrebellion.com/) of the website. The current combination might look nice but it's not very usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `width` and set a negative `margin-right`. Keep the `padding` and don't use `overflow:hidden`, otherwise the content will get cut or too close to the border.

```
blockquote {
    /* width: 200px; no width!*/
    margin-right: -6px; /*this is the code*/
}
```

[image: Aligned to the right]

Answer (score 1):

A JSfiddle would be useful but

```
#stuff > blockquote {
overflow:hidden;
}
```

seems to do the trick.

[image]